# Keep an API call private/protected

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, ajax, sinatra

I'm working on a web app that is mostly static - just HTML/CSS/JS + assets. I'm using a Rack server (Thin, actually) to serve it.

While the app is mostly static, there are a couple of server-side needs that have cropped up along the way. Since the app needs to interact with those needs via JavaScript, I've added Sinatra to the stack to allow me to easily set up some routes to serve as a simple API.

One such API call is to send an email - the web app needs a way to send an email to users. I set up a route (/api/mail) that can be called with a POST that includes a JSON object, and Ruby will fire off an email (via SendGrid).

Here's my issue - by nature, these API calls are public. Most of the time, that is fine - but with the email API, I want to protect it so that nobody can just start sending malicious emails with a simple POST, posing as my app.

Problem is, I'm not quite sure how to authenticate this. The web app itself is the client, not the user, so a password or API key seems worthless, since anyone could just sniff out the POST header and grab the credentials that the app is posting to the API.

Is encrypting everything via SSL my only option, or am I missing some glaringly obvious solution?

Comment: How would SSL help you here? What are you trying to protect from whom?

Comment: I'm trying to protect against anonymous users hijacking my email API by being able make a simple public POST call. I don't want anybody to just be able to send any emails they want for two reasons - it would be expensive, and it would be a security risk (malicious users posing as my app). I figured an API key (or password or something) could be passed in the POST to verify it is my site making the call, but it needs to be SSL encrypted to keep prying eyes from snatching the key from the POST header.

Comment: SSL authenticates the server to the client and keeps the data encrypted in transport. But it does not authenticate the client. Anyone can either (a) open their browser and see the API key embedded in the form page, or (b) write a script that downloads the form page and get to it programmatically. You can password-protect the access to your API (so it is basically not public anymore), but that just means you trust whoever has account on your system. I think the basic question is, whom do you want to trust to call this API.

Comment: @ykaganovich There are no accounts, there are no users. This is a client-side, static app. It's the app itself I want to trust. There will be a button on the site that, when clicked, lets users email a list of items to themselves (they'll only specify their email address). The JavaScript in the client-side app will make an AJAX POST call to the API, which will send the email. I just want to verify that call is coming from the app, and not from someone who makes a POST from a different website, or opens up the console in their browser and makes their own AJAX call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of the day, anything you do can easily be scraped. I would do some aggressive rate limiting by ip and session, don't think if anything else would be possible (or effective)

Comment: Even with SSL, the POST calls could be scraped?

Comment: @idollar with SSL, your traffic within network is encrypted but if some one wrote a browser bot, than in that case you have to do some checks at server side as Matt mentioned.

Comment: @Adeel So what server-side checks can I implement to verify it is my app making the call, and not some random user making a POST? Rate limiting doesn't feel like a solution, because I don't want anybody to use the email API to maliciously pose as my app, whether 1 time or 1000 times.

Comment: @idollar in your scenerio where the API link is public, mostly use IP checks and is done by companies like Google and Yahoo. Another solution to authenticate users and do checks on user. e.g. Hit URL 1 time in 10 seconds etc

Comment: @Adeel Could you elaborate more? I can't authenticate users - there is no DB for this app, no logged users. I'll probably implement some form of rate-limiting to avoid abuse (excessive button clicking), but what I really need to do is verify that the call to the API is coming from my app, and nowhere else. I don't see how rate-limiting will ensure that.

Comment: @ilollar Http is a stateless protocol, to maintain state you often use cookies, sessions, so it is very difficult to detect that the Request comes from your application or simulate from some other app as the cookies/session based requests are easily simulated. a simple solution is check [Referrer] header(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer)

Comment: @Adeel Yes, I guess I could check the HTTP referrer, though that could easily be spoofed as well...

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, my solution for this problem is to add the suggested rate limiting, and also locked down the subject and body copy for the email on the server-side (not being passed from the client-side). That way, it is isn't possible for someone to hijack my API to send malicious emails posing as my app. If they really wanted to, they could just send random, pre-defined emails, but I doubt anyone would find that fun enough to target for excessive abuse. Thanks for all your help, guys!